# Does Office365 only have a single MX record per account?

Tags: email, domain-name-system

When setting up DNS records for clients moving to hosted email, typically there are multiple MX records created.

I have a client using Office365, and the DNS section of the Admin tool only lists a single MX option.

Is this something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, Office 365 utilizes a single MX DNS record.  Behind the scenes Microsoft uses their network to spread the DNS and MX servers around the world.  They perform geo-DNS resolutions for you to find current up servers and the closest one to you.

Nothing to be worried about.

[From Microsoft](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/150/t/13268.aspx)